# How can I open a `.rar` file if Solid Explorer fails?

Tags: file-archives

I have the app Solid Explorer installed but the .rar file doesn't seem to be opening properly.  Which tool can I use to extract .rar files properly?

OS:  4.1.1
Device: S3

Answer (score 1):

Try [B1 Free Archiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.b1.android.archiver), or [AndroZip™ File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agilesoftresource). If the file still doesn't open properly, it might be possible that the archive is corrupt. Try opening the same archive on PC as well, just to be sure.

Comment: I don't have PC access but I'll try the other methods.

Answer (score -1):

Solid Explorer should be able to open RAR files. Try opening the file on a PC, as it may be corrupted.